# how to open google books app with a button click

Tags: java, android

hello I am building a launcher for education I have a button that i need it to open the google books app from the device heres the code To the button:

```
case 3:
                        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            setMenuLeftIconColor(view, 1);
                        }
                        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            if (appMode == 3) {
                                setAppMode(0);
                            }
                            else {
                                if ((motionEvent.getEventTime() - motionEvent.getDownTime()) <= 300) {
                                    setMenuLeftIconColor(view, 0);
                                    try {
                                        startActivity(new Intent("googlebooks code here", null));
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Google Books is NOT Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    setAppMode(3);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
```

any help would be amazing

Thanks in advance guys

Chris

Comment: Since you're creating a launcher for education, you should also check out the google books widget that allows you to create a widget for a particular book you might want to open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package name for [Google Play Books](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.books) is `com.google.android.apps.books` (the end of the URL). Using that, you can launch the app using code such as:

```
String PLAY_BOOKS_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.apps.books";
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
Intent launchIntent = packageManager
    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(PLAY_BOOKS_PACKAGE_NAME);
if (launchIntent != null) {
    startActivity(launchIntent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Google Books is NOT Installed",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: @ianhanniballake how about view book which class name should I add to ComponentName?

Comment: @IshworKhanal - there is no public API for deep linking into a specific book.

Comment: @ianhanniballake so you mean we can just launch the google book app but can not send action type to view the book accessing from local external storage?